# Is there any way to render value on the basis of clicked item from an array in react using router?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-router

My List comp simply renders me the list of a cricketer from a json file on click of a button from Home comp. When I am clicking on the button I am able to see list of cricketer name but unable to obtain detailList comp on clicking list results. Please help me since I am new in React and learning routing.

My Home Comp

```
     import React from 'react'
     import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

    function Home() {
    return (
    <div>
        <button>Display Not Found</button>
        <Link to="/List"><button>Show Cricketer List</button></Link>
         </div>)}
       export default Home
```

My Cricketer Details Comp

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CricketerData from './EmployeeList.json'

class CrickterDetails extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
             <div>
             {CricketerData.map((Detail, index) => {
             return  
                  <div>
                        <p>Employee ID: {Detail.id}</p>
                        <p>First Name: {Detail.firstname}</p>
                        <p>Last Name: {Detail.lastname}</p>
                        <p>Address: {Detail.Postalcode}</p>
                        <p>City: {Detail.Postalcode}</p>
                        <p>Country: {Detail.country}</p>
                  </div> ) })}
        </div>
        </Router> )}}

  export default CrickterDetails
```

My List component:

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react'
       import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
       import CricketerList from './EmployeeList.json'
       class List extends Component {

        render() {
        return (
         <div>
            {CricketerList.map((List, index) => {
              return <Link to={`/CricketerDetails/${List.id}`}> <h1 
        key="index">{List.firstname}</h1></Link>)}
          </div>
    )}}
   export default List
```

My App.js file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
    import List from './components/List';
    import CricketerDetails from './components/CricketerDetails'

    function App() {
     return (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
      <Home />
      <Route path="/List" exact component={EmployeeList} />
      <Route path="/CricketerDetails/:id" exact component={CricketerDetails} />
```

My JSON file

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Virat",
    "lastname": "Kohli",
    "Address": "501-10th Ave.E.Apt.2A",
    "City": "New-Delhi",
    "country": "India"
    rw
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "David",
    "lastname": "Warner",
    "Address": "502-20th Ave.E.Apt.2A",
    "City": "Brisbane",
    "country": "Aus"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "MS",
    "lastname": "Dhoni",
    "Address": "511-20th Ave.E.Apt.2A",
    "City": "Ranchi",
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Root",
    "Address": "507 -20th Ave.E.Apt.2A",
    "City": "London",
    "country": "Eng"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "firstname": "Steve",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "Address": "507 - 20th Ave.E.Apt.2A",
    "City": "Seattle,",
    "country": "Aus"
  }
]
```

Comment: I am able to render CricketerDetaills but not the one on which have clicked instead all the json list data. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, issue is because you are not using `id` in URL for details view.
Check the sample code,

1. Basically try getting the id value from url (Slightly may differ based on react router version)
2. Find correct Detail object to show

Update: Change to use functional component and getting id using `useParams` hook.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import CricketerData from "./EmployeeList.json";

const CrickterDetails = () => {
  // get the id from url
  let { id } = useParams();
  // Get the "Detail" from list by finding based on url id.
  const Detail = CricketerData.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (!Detail) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Employee ID: {Detail.id}</p>
      <p>First Name: {Detail.firstname}</p>
      <p>Last Name: {Detail.lastname}</p>
      <p>Address: {Detail.Postalcode}</p>
      <p>City: {Detail.Postalcode}</p>
      <p>Country: {Detail.country}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrickterDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your effort but it didn't render anything on UI on clicking the list. Though in the URL it is taking me to the exact  ID which is clicked.

Comment: No, it's not working. After clicking on particular list name its showing blank on UI, means no value is rendering on UI.

Comment: Can you update the question with StackBlitz or similar online code sandbox, to see the problem?